# Firebase detect email verification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user verifies their email address, I want to receive some notification on my client app (iOS/Android).

I need this to ensure that I can unlock additional capabilities for those users whose address is verified. How can I achieve this?

Currently, the only way to do this is to call the `reload` method on the `User` object. However, it is not an ideal way of dealing with this situation – after all, I have no idea when they would click on the link. So, performing a reload every time my app becomes active seems excessive.

Maybe there is a trigger which I missed?

Comment: Email verification happens when the user clicks the link in their mail app. There is no notification from this server-side operation to your client-side app.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I do is, each app launch I query the user object for its verification status; if it's not verified I send a verif request right there, if not sent before, and if it is and it's the first time, I show some thank you text and move on. I don't think there's an actual notification you can hook with for when the user clicks the link in the email, but alternatively you could build an admin node function server side to check every now and then for verifications and send pushes to the relevant devices.

Comment: How do you query the user object for its verification status? For me, `isEmailVerified` property remains `false` unless I call `reload` on the user

Comment: Mmm, yes as far as I know, there's just -isEmailVerified-, but so far I've never had the need to check immediately, I just wait till the next app launch and naturally by then, the user object is refreshed... Firebase is a lazy loader, for performance reasons so I can see the issue here